# comparison of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays say `a = [1,2,3]` and `b=[1,2,3]`

if i do `(a==b)` it returns false. how to compare two arrays with same values?

`a[0]==b[0]` will return true, but how can we compare two arrays instead of 2 same elements inside two different arrays?

Comment: You have to write the code to loop through all the elements.

Comment: @Pointy usually i do that. but just wanted to know is there any way other than looping?

Comment: No, there is no built-in array comparison facility in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare 2 arrays, you could use `JSON.stringify`

```
JSON.stringify([1,2,3]) === JSON.stringify([1,2,3]); //=> true
```

It will also compare [nested] Objects within the array, or [nested] Arrays within an Array:

```
JSON.stringify([1,2,3,{a:1,b:2}]) === 
  JSON.stringify([1,2,3,{'a':1,b:2}]); //=> true

JSON.stringify([1,2,3,{a:1,b:2,c:{a:1,b:2}}]) === 
  JSON.stringify([1,2,3,{'a':1,b:2,c:{a:1,b:2}}]); //=> true

JSON.stringify([1,2,3,{a:1,b:2,c:[4,5,6,[7,8,9]]}]) === 
  JSON.stringify([1,2,3,{'a':1,b:2,c:[4,5,6,[7,8,9]]}]); //=> true
```

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/VXgss/), I've played a bit with the idea

Comment: seems like answer i am looking for, but if i have objects inside the array will it return true?

Comment: Yes, if the objects are equal: `JSON.stringify([1,2,3,{a:1,b:2}]) === JSON.stringify([1,2,3,{a:1,b:2}]);` returns `true`

Comment: This won't work if objects contain equal pairs of key:value but in different order. You can't compare objects converting them to string. That's asking for trouble.

Comment: @alexandernst: it depends on how you want to use it. It won't work for differently sorted arrays with equal values either. In such cases, sorting the arrays/object[-keys] before comparing could be an option. There are no complete or native javascript solutions, the JSON idea is one that's fairly usable imo.

Comment: Comparing objects by converting them to a string isn't a good idea in any language, nor a good option for anything. Don't try to compare lemons with apples by painting the lemons in red.

Comment: @KooiInc: Sorting object (non-array) keys is not an option. There is no way to define an order unless you move the keys to a separate Array. Also, with `stringify`, you are limited to comparison of JSON supported data types. For example, Function comparison or properties that have `undefined` can cause failures.

Comment: @shreedhar: There's no guarantee in the language or in JSON of any particular order of object properties. One stringify call could produce `'{"a":1,"b":2}'` and the other could produce `'{"b":2,"a":1}'`. There's no mechanism available for defining property order.

Answer (score 6):

You have 2 options.

Fisrt one is to use some kind of function made by yourself that will iterate over each key from both arrays and compare them.

Second option is to use `isEqual`  from `_.underscore` (a really nice JS library, http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual )
This will work for both arrays and objects.

I'd use the second one as it's easier.

```
var a = {'a' : '1', 'b' : '2', 'c' : '3'};
var b = {'a' : '1', 'b' : '2', 'c' : '3'};
_.isEqual(a, b) // --> true
```

Note that order doesn't matter in objects, so you could have

```
var a = {'a' : '1', 'b' : '2', 'c' : '3'};
var b = {'c' : '3', 'b' : '2', 'a' : '1'}
_.isEqual(a, b) // --> also true
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function array_compare(a, b)
{
    // if lengths are different, arrays aren't equal
    if(a.length != b.length)
       return false;

    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
       if(a[i] != b[i])
          return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `array_compare([1,2,3,{a:1,b:2}],[1,2,3,{a:1,b:2}])` returns `false` though, so I suppose this is only usable with arrays containing primitive values.

Answer (score 6):

If you know what (not) to expect in your array you could use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
a.join() == b.join()
```

I know, this is far from bulletproof, but it can be usable some cases (when you know the order in both arrays will be the same).

Comment: But what about this? `["a,b"].join() == ["a","b"].join()`

Comment: Then you need a custom separator. I know, using join is not bulletproof but it will work fine I you more or less know what (not) to expect in your array.

Comment: A separator also doesn't work in all cases; e.g. `["a", "b"].join("||") == ["a||b"].join("||")`

Comment: True, this will only work in some cases (see previous comment). I've updated the answer to underline that.

Answer (score 2):

`(a==b)` is doing a reference comparaison not a content comparaison.

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) brings some feature for that.

Comment: is there any way to compare two arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Try using javascripts **[Join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** method to convert the two arrays to strings and then compage the strings:

**[Join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):** `The string conversions of all array elements are joined into one string.`

```
var a1 = array1.join();
var a2 = array2.join();

if(a1 == a2){
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must write code to compare each element of an array to accomplish your objective.

```
// this is one way of doing it, and there are caveats about using instanceOf. 
// Its just one example, and presumes primitive types.
function areArrayElementsEqual(a1, a2)
{
    if (a1 instanceof Array) && (a2 instanceof Array)
    {
        if (a1.length!=a2.length)
            return false;
        else{
           var x;
           for (x=0;x<a1.length; x++)
              if (a1[x]!=a2[x])
                 return false;
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the shortest way I found:

```
""+ar1==""+ar2
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pmt4q/4/)

Comment: This returns a false positive if the objects inside the array aren't equal. E.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/Pmt4q/5/